# Retrieving images from database in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to store and retrieve images from sql database in Delphi XE.

My code:

```
TBlobField(query.FieldByName('image')).SaveToStream(MStream);    
Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(MStream);
```

Comment: What have you done ? What is the exact problem you're having ? Do you have some error message ? Can you show us the relevant portion of code ?

Comment: Well, it's easy to see what that fails!

Comment: 15 questions, only one accepted answer. That's something!

Comment: David, banita doesn't saw your link. his only concern is about that code.

Comment: @Radu Indeed. I just can't find enough motivation to answer.

Comment: @David: or to repeat the comments about searching first...

Comment: It seems that this question is too hard for you, me, Cosmin, and others...

Comment: @David, good point in your last two comments. I'll take care of the  answer I just posted to a different question. It was probably wrong anyway. :)

Comment: Nice balance, -4 at question and all comments except OP's are voted as great :) @banita - isn't that a reason to amend yourself ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set the stream position to 0 between saving from the database and reading from the image.

Comment: You should have read the comments to the original question before answering. There's a point being made.

Comment: There is no point to not answering.  Its not a game about collecting points, its about helping out when you can.

Comment: @Gregor: not signing which answer solved the problem, the site looses parts of its utility - and you help less people. Some times, the most voted was not the selected - because the OP solved the problem with that answer or just the most voted appeared AFTER the selecion of accepted answer.

Comment: Maybe none of the answers solved his problems?

Comment: @Gregor: So the OP has posted 13 questions and received answers that solved his problem only once? Then why didn't the OP post follow-up questions about the same topic? It's a matter of taking advantage of people and not having the courtesy to work with the community. The point is that this site was set up to work a certain way, and if you're willing to use it you should be willing to support it as designed.